# MacOS Toolbar Space makes Items disappear despite sufficient space

Tags: swift, macos, toolbar, swiftui-navigationview

I created a macOS App with a NavigationView and a Toolbar.
Somehow next to my toolbarItem there is a lot of space.. So whenever I change the size of my apps window the toolbarItem disappears. Despite there is still a lot of space for my item.
I did not find out how to reduce that space..
Can you help me?

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
    }
       .toolbar(content: {
          ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
             Image(systemName: "gearshape")
                .frame(height: 20)
          }
       })
```

[image]

Comment: A Workaround is to set the minWidth of the detail view, and not allowing to set to the small width.

Comment: What do you mean with small width? And with detail view do you mean the lower right view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
The title is existing and just invisible.
You can remove the title by adding `.windowToolbarStyle(.unifiedCompact(showsTitle: false))`
to the WindowGroup.